# google custom search error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) )

Tags: php, google-search, parse-error

I have used google custom search engine and used their code provided in my website.

I have this issue in the (search.php) that I cant place the < ?php endif; ?> and I get an error ( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) )

How can I add that endif on the search.php file ?

---

this is part where I use the google code:

```
<?php  $j=0; $i =0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<script>

  (function() {

    var cx = '000306723311332550300:g5hpmnp8s68';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();

</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: Tip: if you want to make a code block, highlight the text and hit the `{}` button in the editor, or ctrl-K, which indents everything by 4 spaces.

Comment: You're using the alternative syntax, and have no `endif` or `endwhile`

Comment: Wheres your `endif`?

Comment: the endif I add is at the end after the </gcse:search>

Comment: is there any other way to end the loop ? or shall I add the endif in another place ??

Comment: As @MarcB suggested, you need an endwhile before your endif.  The endwhile ends the loop.  The endif ends the condition have_posts().

Comment: why does that script need to be in a loop anyways? nothing in it depends on anything the PHP stuff is doing, so you're just dumping out the **SAME** script block however many times the loop runs.

Comment: forgive me if I am a newbie !! but I added the endwile before endif and still getting an error !! can you show the code of both of them to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change where to add the code and here is the full code of search.php

```
<?php $mts_options = get_option('point'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page" class="home-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="article">
            <h1 class="postsby">
                <span><?php _e("Search Results for:", "mythemeshop"); ?></span> <?php the_search_query(); ?>
            </h1>   
            <?php  $j=0; $i =0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '000306723311332550300:tfoukb5efrq';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="no-results">
                    <h5><?php _e('No Results found. We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.', 'mythemeshop'); ?></h5>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!--noResults-->
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <!--Start Pagination-->
            <?php if ( isset($mts_options['mts_pagenavigation']) && $mts_options['mts_pagenavigation'] == '1' ) { ?>
                <?php  $additional_loop = 0; global $additional_loop; mts_pagination($additional_loop['max_num_pages']); ?>           
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                        <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <!--End Pagination-->           
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```